# $\sigma$-field structure determined by indicator functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This is Exercise 2.10 from *Probability and Measure*:

> (a) Show that if $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ contains every subset of $\Omega$, then for each pair $\omega$ and $\omega'$ of distinct points in $\Omega$ there is an $A$ in $\mathscr{A}$ such that $I_A(\omega) \neq I_A(\omega')$.

> (b) Show that the reverse implication holds if $\Omega$ is countable.

I am able to show part (a) as follows: If there exists a pair $\omega$ and $\omega'$ of distinct points in $\Omega$ such that for all $A \in \mathscr{A}$, $I_A(\omega) = I_A(\omega')$. Define
$$\mathscr{G} = \{A \subset \Omega: I_A(\omega) = I_A(\omega')\},$$
then $\mathscr{G}$ is a $\sigma$-field and $\mathscr{A} \subset \mathscr{G}$, whence $\sigma(\mathscr{A}) \subset \mathscr{G}$.  Therefore $\mathscr{G}$ contains every subset of $\Omega$.  However for $A = \{\omega\}$, $I_A(\omega) = 1 \neq I_A(\omega') = 0$, contradiction.

When I tried to apply the same proof by contradiction argument to part (b), I got some obstacles: suppose $\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2, \ldots\}$ is countable and assume some subsets are not contained in $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$, it is hard to reach the contradiction (basically due to that $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ is too complicated to exhaust).  Alternatively, I was able to show that $\{\{\omega_1\}, \{\omega_2\}, \ldots\}$ forms an *$\mathscr{A}$-partition* (*Probability and Measure*, pp.57 - 58) of $\Omega$, but this seems not helpful unless it can be shown that every $\mathscr{A}$-equivalence class is a member of $\mathscr{A}$.  Therefore, I am seeking for a proof to part (b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\omega_0\in\Omega$. Then for any $\omega\in\Omega$ we can find $A_\omega\in\sigma(\mathscr A)$ s.t. $\mathbf1_{A_\omega}(\omega_0)=1$ but $\mathbf1_{A_\omega}(\omega)=0$. So we have a countable intersection
$$\{\omega_0\}=\bigcap_{\omega\in\Omega\setminus\{\omega_0\}}A_\omega\in\sigma(\mathscr A).$$
So any singleton of $\Omega$ is in $\sigma(\mathscr A)$, and because $\Omega$ is countable, we can get any subset of $\Omega$ via countable unions of singletons.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer.  Overall I believe it is the right direction. Just one more thing, the $A_\omega$ you mentioned could result in $I_{A_\omega}(\omega_0) = 0$ while $I_{A_\omega}(\omega) = 1$. But I think this is easy to fix by considering $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ and complement.

Comment: @Zhanxiong yes it doesn't matter really, if needed take the complement, we're still inside $\sigma(\mathscr A)$ so the intersection is too.